# local scope record on the stack

Tags: c, scope, stack

Consider the following C function.
Does opening the braces to create a local scope make compilers create a record on the stack to mantain the variables declared in the scope ?

```
void function()  
{  
    int q,r;
    ...
    {  
        int i = 0;
        int j = 3;  
        q = j + 1;  
    }
    ... 
}
```

If so , do compilers act the same with while blocks?

example:

```
void function()  
{  
    int q,r;
    ...    
    while(conditions)  
    {  
        int i = 0;  
        int j = 3;    
        q = j + 1;    
    }
    ... 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The arrangement of the stack is not specified by the C standard.

Curly braces (`{}`) introduce a new scope, so in principle, yes, this could create a new frame on the stack.  But the compiler may choose to optimise this overhead away.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on compiler. Good modern compiler would optimize this code. It would count

```
int j = 3;
q=j+1;
```

at compilation time and make something like

```
q=4;
```

The same for the second example. The variable j would be put on stack or maybe even in a register, its value set as 3 and then would be processed through cycle iterations.

Answer (score 1):

`{}` is called the compound statement (also called block ) and it introduces a new block scope. It means here:

```
void function(void)
{
    int q,r;
    ...

   {  
       int i = 0;
       int j = 3;  
       q = j + 1;  
   }
   ...
```

}

`q` and `r` are destroyed at the end of the function; `i` and `j` are destroyed at the end of the local block scope. The lifetime of an automatic object is limited to the block where it is declared.

For iteration statement like the `while` statement, this is exactly the same, the `while` statement is defined as:

```
while (expression) statement
```

If you use a compound statement (a block) for the statement in `while` it will also introduce a new scope.

Now on the stack level, C does no require a stack so it implementation details.

Comment: so q,r and i,j could be created on different records?

Comment: @user986437 `q`,`r` and `i`,`j` have different different lexical scope and different lifetime.

Comment: Note that `i` and `j` in the `while` loop are reinitialized on each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Based on behavior I've seen in the past, I'd say "probably not".  IME, only a single stack frame gets created for all the function's variables, regardless of how they're scoped within the function.

Restricted scoping is something the compiler enforces at *translation* time; there's no real need to do it at run time.

Comment: I see...please help me clear this point.                             Lets suppose I have a pc with a few kbs of RAM, would using a record for each scope the programmer creates help large programs run on my pc ?

Comment: If you're really limited on memory, creating a whole stack frame for each scope would probably make the situation *worse*. Not to mention it would create a runtime performance penalty.